# Do WebClient/WebRequest call back on the calling thread?

Tags: silverlight, asynchronous, callback, webclient

In Silverlight, WCF proxies always make their callbacks on the calling thread. Do WebRequest and WebClient have this behavior?

Comment: Can you provide a reference for "WCF proxies always make their callbacks on the calling thread"?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Sure: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072242/updating-ui-components-from-an-async-callback/4075579#4075579

Comment: Interestingly enough, it appears that the question I linked to actually answers this question. Wish I had found that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072242/updating-ui-components-from-an-async-callback/4075579#4075579) while searching around for a reference to confirm that WCF proxies do in fact call back on the same thread.

Assuming that Joe is correct (have no reason to believe he's not), it looks like WebClient will post the callback to the calling thread, but HttpWebRequest will not.